# Adjusting the size of chart while copying from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy my chart from one sheet to another.

In my sheets I have my charts in different sizes. But in sheet2, I would like to have my charts in the same height and width.

Can anyone suggest how I can do it?

I have the below code running, just to copy the charts. I would like to have them in regular size.

```
Sub Overview()
Sheets("Cat").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
Sheets("Overview").Select
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (PNG)", Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False
Range("B5").Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, you want to resize all your chats in the sheet, so that they will have all the same width and height.

The Code below will run trhough all charts i a sheet and will set new Values for the width and height and will change the Position aswell.

```
'Set Position off all Charts
    Dim intTop As Integer
    Dim intLeft As Integer
    Dim idx As Integer
    intTop = 275 'start Position from the Top for the first chart
    intLeft = 15 'strat positon from the left for the first chart
    idx = 0

    wsDia.Select
    For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        myChart.Width = 450
        myChart.Height = 200
        myChart.Top = intTop
        myChart.Left = intLeft

        intLeft = intLeft + 465
        idx = idx + 1
        If idx = 4 Then 'after 4 Charts, go to next row of charts
            intLeft = 15
            intTop = intTop + 230
            idx = 0
        End If

    Next myChart
```

**Update:**

If you want to change the height of a PNG Picture you need to loop like this:

The first Loop is if you want the to set the Size with a locked Ratio. That means if you set the Height to 500 the Width will set automaticly.

```
For Each mypNg In ActiveSheet.Shapes


    mypNg.Height = 500
Next
```

If you want the Ratio unlocket you have to add:

```
    mypNg.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
```

Comment: they don't belong to chart category, I am copy pasting them in sheet2, so they are in the form of image Png format

Comment: @Jenny ok. is there a reason why you are copy the Charts as Image?

Comment: Because In one sheet, I would like to have the consolidated result from different sheet. So I just copy the image

Comment: @ Jenny Ok got that. One question more. Do you now if the Data Source of the Charts will change later during work? Because then i would recomand that you copy the Chart.

Comment: ya., they will change

Comment: @ jenny ok. becuase if you have the Charts a PNG the chart will not be Updated. So you need to restart the Makro Every time the Data changes. When you copy the Charts, the Chart will be Updated if the Data CHanges

Comment: I have an button to refresh them everytime . SO it is not an problem. I can have them In Png. I just need to resize the images

Comment: @ ok. Updated my Answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150302/discussion-between-jenny-and-moosli).

Comment: can you also tell me how I can delete the images in my sheet from row 5. ?

Comment: @ Jenny just use the Loop and insert **mypNg.Delete** that would delete all PNG Pictures

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Dim Cht As Chart
Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
Set Ws = Sheets("Cat")
Set toWs = Sheets("Overview")
Set Cht = Ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart
Cht.CopyPicture
toWs.Activate
Range("b5").Activate
toWs.Paste
```